# Python web crawler, print each step in different list

Tags: python, list, hyperlink, web-crawler

I have made a web crawler with help of tutorial which gets all links from given url and you can give pass it a number which correspond steps/depth of how far it goes for links. Now currently when you define a number in `scraperOut = scraper(url,3)` which is currently number 3, the crawler goes 3 steps in depth and appends links to same list. My question is how to and what to modify in code so I could choose to print each list separetely not all appended in one list, or for example to print out just 2nd step list? The entire code looks like this:

```
import urllib
import re
import time
from threading import Thread
import MySQLdb
import mechanize
import readability
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from readability.readability import Document
import urlparse

url = "http://www.adbnews.com/area51/"

def scraper(root,steps):
    urls = [root]
    visited = [root]
    counter = 0
    while counter < steps:
        step_url = scrapeStep(urls)
        urls = []
        for u in step_url:
            if u not in visited:
                urls.append(u)
                visited.append(u)
        counter +=1

    return visited

def scrapeStep(root):
    result_urls = []
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

    for url in root:
        try:
            br.open(url)
            for link in br.links():
                newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
                result_urls.append(newurl)
        except:
            print "error"
    return result_urls

d = {}
threadlist = []

def getReadableArticle(url):
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

    html = br.open(url).read()

    readable_article = Document(html).summary()
    readable_title = Document(html).short_title()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(readable_article)

    final_article = soup.text

    links = soup.findAll('img', src=True)

    return readable_title
    return final_article

def dungalo(urls):
    article_text = getReadableArticle(urls)[0]
    d[urls] = article_text

def getMultiHtml(urlsList):
    for urlsl in urlsList:
        try:
            t = Thread(target=dungalo, args=(urls1,))
            threadlist.append(t)
            t.start()
        except:
            nnn = True

    for g in threadlist:
        g.join()

    return d


scraperOut = scraper(url,3)

for s in scraperOut:
    print s

#print scraperOut
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you change the section of your code that reads:

```
    return readable_title
    return final_article
```

to read:

```
    print readable_title
    return final_article
```

You will get a lot of what you are asking for and have a lot more chance that your code will work!  N.B. With the original code you will never return `final_article` as it returns `readable_title` first.

Comment: thank you, I've changed that, but that is not my main problem